# Populating a combobox from 2 different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm very new to VBA programming and this is only me second user form database. I am trying to initialize combo boxes in a user form, but the data needs to be in 2 different sheets in the same work book. I have no issue when it needs to initialize from only one sheet, but cannot find a solution to use 2 sheets in the same form. The code below is what I currently have. What I need to do is move the first line data (Hengelaar List) to a separate sheet called "Lede Lys", but have no idea how to code this new sheet into the existing Private sub.

I really hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Worksheets("Reference sheet")
    ***Hengelaar.List = .Range("b2:b500").Value
    Permitdatum.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")***
    Spesie1.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie2.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie3.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie4.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie5.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie6.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie7.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie8.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie9.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    Spesie10.List = .Range("A2:A17").Value
    TotalKilos.Value = ("")
    Permitdatum.Value = ("")


End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Specify the worksheet for each range object: `Hengelaar.List = Worksheets("Lede Lys").Range("b2:b500").Value`

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked a charm. I learn something new every time I try to develop something new.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Sheets(2).Range("A1:A3")
Set rng2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:a3")

comboboxValue = _
Split(Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng1.Value), ",") & "," _
   & Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng2.Value), ","), ",")
   Me.ComboBox1.List = comboboxValue

End Sub
```

Comment: Range can be said like 
          Set rng1 = Sheets("SheetName1").Range("A1:A3")
          Set rng2 = Sheets("SheetName2").Range("A1:a3")